# I am not being redirected to the page i want to be redirected to while making a website using django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.conf.urls import url
from .models import Category,Product
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth

def signup(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        first_name=request.POST['first_name']
        last_name=request.POST['last_name']
        email=request.POST['email']
        mobile=request.POST['mobile']
        password=request.POST['password']
        cpassword=request.POST['cpassword']

        user=User.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name,email=email,mobile=mobile,password=password)

        user.save();
        
        return redirect('/')

    else:
        return render(request,"signup.html")
```

This is the form i am using in the html page

```
 <form class="row contact_form" action="signup" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

When i enter data in the form and click on submit it redirects me to /signup/signup (Page not found) instead of index.html(home).Also the user data is not being saved in postgresql auth_user.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't redirect you (HTTP 302), you're simply posting to an URL beneath your current url named `signup` (because the form specifies `action="signup"`).

What you want to do instead is:

```
<form class="row contact_form" action="." method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

then you will be posting to the view that displays the form.

Comment: I am getting this error now: User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mobile' I went to postgres and there created a column named mobile(by right clicking it and creating new column)

Comment: That is an entirely new question which you should ask separately.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63077697/i-am-working-on-a-website-that-requires-users-to-register-and-login-but-having-p

Comment: Please help here.