# I am working on a website that requires users to register and login but Having problem in adding an additional field to auth_user using django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have this form in html of my site

```
   <form class="row contact_form" action="." method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="first_name" value=""
                                placeholder="First Name" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="last_name" value=""
                                placeholder="Last Name" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" value=""
                                placeholder="Mobile Number" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value=""
                                placeholder="Email" required>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" value=""
                                placeholder="Password" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group p_star">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="cpassword" name="cpassword" value=""
                                placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                           
                            <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn_3">
                                SignUp
                            </button>
                            
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Now the problem I am facing is:
1)When I try to post data it shows me an error that username is required which i dont want(create_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username').
2)There is no mobile number section in auth_user which i want.
I have tried reading the django docs but couldnt understand(OnetoOne thing and custom usermodel thing I couldnt understand both)

Here is my views.py

```
def signup(request):

     if request.method == "POST":
          first_name=request.POST['first_name']
          last_name=request.POST['last_name']
          email=request.POST['email']
          mobile=request.POST['mobile']
          password=request.POST['password']
          cpassword=request.POST['cpassword']
          username=request.POST['username']

    user=User.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name,email=email,password=password,mobile=mobile)

    user.save();
    
    return redirect('/')

     else:
            return render(request,"signup.html")
```

(The indentations are correct)

Also I want that the users can login using mobile number or email but I dint find any explanation for that.

Comment: your indentation does not make any sense.. what does the last else belong to?

Comment: The last else is after the if above.I might have made this error while copying it here. In original code its correct

Comment: eh... please edit your post and fix it...?

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
...

class MyUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # add other custom fields
    first_name = models.CharField(...)
    ...
# create as
user = User.objects.create_user(username=email,...)
my_user = MyUser.objects.create(user=user, first_name=first_name, ...)

# authenticate as
user.authenticate(username=email, password=password)
```

[This might help](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#onetoone)

[Django default auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/)

Comment: How to add a mobile number field too?And will your code make username not required.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged, since there is no way to determine your intention when your code is problematic...